# How to deploy several Azure Functions with VSTS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I have created in Azure 2 Azure Functions resources with the following names:

- FrontApiFunctions
- PostProcessingFunctions

My Visual Studio solutions is like this:

```
AllFunctions.sln
|- FrontApiFunctions
   |- FrontApiFunctions.csproj
   |- FrontApiFunctions.cs
|- PostProcessingFunctions
   |- PostProcessingFunctions.csproj
   |- PostProcessingFunctions.cs
```

In VSTS what are the steps to deploy:

- FrontApiFunctions.csproj to the FrontApiFunctions resources
- PostProcessingFunctions.csproj to the PostProcessingFunctions resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something similar once, except I built and referenced a class library from a Function App. You should be able to adapt this approach:

1. Build the solution
2. Add a "Copy Files" task to copy the output of the class library into the references of the function app
3. In the Copy Files task, specify the build output of the class library
4. For the `Target Folder`, specify the folder that your Function App is pulling its references from, for example: `#r "References\MyAssembly.dll"`

[image: Function App Build Configuration]

As for the release:

1. Simply use the "Azure App Service Deploy" task
2. The trick here is that while the task looks for a zip file by default, you can override it simply publish the contents of a folder instead (the function app)

[image]